# What is a Hadoop Cluster?

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing

I am confused because I see the word 'Cluster' being used in multiple scenarios.  Which of these below is the proper use of 'Cluster'?

1. All the NameNodes, Job Trackers and Data Nodes
2. One set of NameNode, JobTracker, and DataNodes (there being many more such sets)

Edit:
An example of such confusing line is at [this page](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.18.3/distcp.html): 
`DistCp (distributed copy) is a tool used for large inter/intra-cluster copying`

If all the servers(nodes) together is a cluster, then where is the question of 'inter cluster copying'? If a subset of servers is a cluster, then what exactly is that subset?

Comment: What is "in a given installation"?

Comment: I agree the usage of the word 'installation' is loose. I meant in a given setup of hadoop, all servers (nodes) considered. Please feel free to edit the question or point me to a resource where I can get the background to frame the question better (or to find an answer).. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Hadoop cluster is a combination of Master & Slave nodes, the Master nodes being `NameNode, Secondary NameNode and Job Tracker` & the Slave nodes being `DataNodes and TaskTrackers`. In any hadoop cluster, there is 1 instance of the Master nodes, i.e `1 NameNode, 1 Secondary NameNode and 1 Job Tracker` and `multiple slave nodes (dataNodes and taskTrackers)`

Comment: Thank you. What if there are multiple `Name Nodes`, like in a NameNode Federation? What would you call a cluster in that context?

Comment: Yes, a NameNode Federation is an improvement to deal with the single point of failure NameNode in earlier hadoop versions. So it would still fall under the same cluster.

Comment: Thanks. So can you tell me what is the scenario when one would have multiple clusters - (see my question edit).

Comment: You may have a large cluster of computers, and only a portion of the cluster would be running Hadoop services. So then the Hadoop cluster would consist of only those nodes running Hadoop. The main cluster would be much larger. Alternatively, you could have totally different Hadoop clusters, each running independently.